# Survival sample size calculation

Tags: r, survival, statistical-power, epidemiology, case-cohort

I want to calculate the sample size for a survival study of patients with acute myeloid leukemia, with two cohorts, one receiving chemotherapy and the other not. I want an event-free survival (EFS) at 1 year of 40% with a margin of 5%. The difference between the two cohorts has to be 5-10%, with a power of 0.8 and alpha of 0.05.

I have considered a non-inferiority design, as the new treatment may not be as efficient but has lower toxicity, and I want to prove that the new treatment is not significantly worse than the reference treatment, which has already been tested. I want a maximum difference in efficiency of 10%. Does this make sense? Would it be better to do a superiority design? I have calculated the sample size for each cohort, which must be the same, using the epi.ssninfb function from the epiR package, but I have seen that there are many R packages (that take into account different types of distribution, constant or non-constant hazard ratios, among other assumptions) and many programs to perform the calculation, and I don't know which is the best method.

The hypotheses planned are:

**Ho:** prob. standard treatment - prob.new treatment >= 0.1

**H1:** prob. standard treatment - prob.new treatment < 0.1

And the R code:

```
install.packages("epiR")
library(epiR)

epi.ssninfb(treat = 0.4, control = 0.4, delta = 0.10, n = NA,  r = 1, 
            power = 0.8, nfractional = TRUE, alpha = 0.05)

$n.total
[1] 593.5255

$n.treat
[1] 296.7627

$n.control
[1] 296.7627

$delta
[1] 0.1

$power
[1] 0.8
```

Has the sample size been correctly determined? I have also found other R functions to perform the calculation, such as ***power.t.test*** (***survival*** package), ***sample.size.NI*** (***dani*** package), ***power.prop.test*** (***stats*** package), ***nSurvival*** (***gsDesign*** package, which requires accrual and follow-up times that I don't have), etc.

I'm very confused. Can anyone help me?

Thank you very much! :)

EI_Stats

Comment: One thing missing from your description is the pattern of accrual into the study. Say that you estimate that you need about 600 total, as in your question. It seems unlikely that you will have 600 patients all set to enter the study at the same time. If patients accrue, say, at 100 per year over 6 years, you can use the longer observation times of those entering earlier to provide more evidence on non-inferiority. The [FDA guidance](https://www.fda.gov/media/78504/download) contains much useful information about planning non-inferiority trials.